# Add javaagent in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, openjpa

I am building a JPA dynamic web project in Eclipse using APACHE OpenJPA. 
I have the following file structure:

```
- User (Model file)
- DataManagerContoller
- JPASerlvet
```

When I tried to run my project on a local Tomcat server, I encountered `The type "class com.rs.u2.u2jpatest.User" has not been enhanced.`

Any idea how I can resolve this problem?

I am assuming I may need to add a `javaagent command` somewhere. But I have no idea where to add the `javaagent command` in Eclipse.

Look forward to an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading through the [OpenJPA Entity Enhancement page](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html).

Comment: I am using OpenJPA Snapshot-1.3 running on Tomcat7 with JAVA6. I followed step by step in the tutorial but still facing "class not enhanced" error. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Use build time enhancement